# Pandas DataFrame how to group (pivot?) rows by values of specified columns, but keeping the original index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to implement Variable Elimination algorithm using Pandas. If anyone is familiar with the sum-out step, given a table where a, b, c are variables (not necessarily boolean-valued) and f is some function (factor) given the values of these variables.

```
       a      b      c      f
0   True   True   True  0.015
1   True   True  False  0.035
2   True  False   True  0.270
3   True  False  False  0.180
4  False   True   True  0.030
5  False   True  False  0.070
6  False  False   True  0.240
7  False  False  False  0.160
```

I want to sum `f`s of all rows where `(a,c)=(T,T)`, also `f`s of all rows where `(a,c)=(T,F)`, `(F,T)`, `(F,F)`. The result looks like

```
       a     c     f
0   True  True  0.285
1   True   False  0.215
2   False  True  0.27
3   False  False  0.23
```

Hence the name "sum-out (`b`)".

The closest I can get is using `pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index.values, columns=['a', 'c'], values='f', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0).sum()` which returns

```
a      c
False  False    xxx
       True     xxx
True   False    xxx
       True     xxx
```

Another `unstack` can give us

```
c      False  True
a
False   xxx   xxx
True    xxx   xxx
```

which is still not what I want.

Note that I can have arbitrarily many variables, and arbitrarily many variables to sum-out (or to keep). So though in this case I can do `pd.pivot_table(df, index=<some of the var left, e.g. a>, columns=<other var left, e.g. c>, values='f', aggfunc=np.sum)` to get the same result, in other cases there may be only one variable left, or too many.

The variables may not be boolean type, but they should have finite & discrete domains.

Also note that my index here are only dummy meaningless index. By "keeping original index" I mean just leave them dummy, but somehow only aggregate along `axis=0`.

In addition, it is also OK if anyone can propose a better multi-dimensional-array like data structure to do the job.

Comment: from your sample data, sum of `(a,c)=(T,T)` returns `0.285`, not `0.57` as your desired output. Is it a typo?

Comment: @AndyL. Yeah I think that's a typo. I must have copied wrong lines from my python shell. Just corrected them! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groupby and agg functions like this.

```
df.groupby(['a','c'])['f'].agg('sum').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am a little curious that if the columns to keep are too many, say 'a' to 'h' instead of 'a' & 'c', will the performance be significantly affected by the index levels?

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not care about `column 'b'` you can drop it and then group by columns `'a' and 'c'` as follows:

```
df1 = df[['a', 'c','f']]
df1 = df1.groupby(['a', 'c']).sum().reset_index()
```

This should return the answer you are looking for. Do not forget to reset the index of the resulting dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! So the same question since you and Boris's answer are quite similar... If the columns to keep are too many, say 'a' to 'h' instead of 'a' & 'c', will the performance be significantly affected by the index levels?

Comment: You can get the answer to your question if you properly time both approaches.